# I am not understanding the module structure and the functionalities of the import statement in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Can anyone please help me understand the module structure of python and how the import works in python.

I wanted to use the `linear_model` of sklearn module in python but these two different codes are acting differently whereas they should have acted the same way. One is giving error and another one is working fine.
[Look at the code in this picture...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dUlb.png)

```
import sklearn as sk # gives error

from sklearn import linear_model # works fine
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import sklearn` corresponds to importing `sklearn/__init__.py`.

[That module does not re-export](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/__init__.py) the subpackage `sklearn.linear_model` (`sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py`) as an attribute.

There's no reason why they should act the same way. Some packages do re-exporting, many (scikit-learn included) don't.